# nextjs router.events.on not called on intial page load

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a working `useEffect` to call my google analytics when changing page.
This works fine when changing pages but when you initially load for the first time or refresh it does not call the `router.events.on`

this is my code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies === true) {
      router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {            
        ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
      });
      return () => {
        router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", () => {
          ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
        });
      };
    }
  }, [router.events]);
```

I thought of using an other `useEffect` to initially call the reactGA but then when changing page it would be called twice, which is not good.

any idea on how to make this work on the initial page load?

Comment: See also: [onRouteChangeCompleted not called on first page load #4662](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4662)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected behaviour - `router.events` is only triggered on client-side page navigations initiated by the Next.js router.

You can call `ReactGA.pageview` on a separate `useEffect` to handle initial page loads.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies === true) {            
        ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves ! Can you please elaborate a bit more: why do you add the `cookies === true` check? Is it required?

Comment: @Q-bart That's a condition that existed in OP's original code. I simply kept the same behaviour from that. If you don't have any condition to trigger the page view, then you don't need the `if` block.